# How do I add a unique identifier column to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame with a column with long strings. I would like to add a unique identifier. I need to keep all the rows but duplicate strings should get the same ID.

I would like to use this new unique identifier later in a merge.

Let's create a df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'longstrings': ['aaaaaaaa', 'asdfasdf', 'bbbbbbbbb', 'asdfasdf', 'aaaaaaaa'], 
     'somevalue': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

Desired output:

```
  longstrings  somevalue  unique_ID
0    aaaaaaaa          1          0
1    asdfasdf          2          1
2   bbbbbbbbb          3          2
3    asdfasdf          4          1
4    aaaaaaaa          5          0
```

I have tried to use groupby:

```
grouped = df.groupby('longstrings')
grouped.transform(lambda ???)
```

I just do not know how to get a good lambda function. Does `grouped`have some kind of index?

I also thought about using a hash-function on my string. However, this does not create handy small numbers. Also, how likely are hash-collisions? My strings are sometimes very similar.

Comment: `pd.factorize(df['longstrings'])[0]`

Comment: What shall I say? Nvm, exactly what I was looking for. Really sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Python has a builtin [hash](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) command which will do what you want.

```
df['unique_id'] = df.longstrings.map(hash)
```